# Unable to identify the WebEdit object in QTP 11

Tags: object, vbscript, qtp

I am facing an issue while set a value in a WebEdit object in a Web based application. The web page has been developed using GWT.

Please find the below code.

```
Function webeditObject(webeditProperty1, webeditValue1, webeditProperty2, webeditValue2) 
   Set WebEditObj=description.Create
   WebEditObj("micclass").value="WebEdit"
   WebEditObj(webeditProperty1).value=webeditValue1
   WebEditObj(webeditProperty2).value=webeditValue2  
   Set webeditObject=WebEditObj
End Function
```

Calling

```
Set webeditObj = webeditObject("class", "grid-dropdownbox", "index" , "36")
If Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebTable(webtableObj).WebElement(webeditObj).Exist(0) Then
                           Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebTable(webtableObj).WebElement(webeditObj).Set dict.Item("id")  

End  If
```

I know till the WebTable its working. But its trying to identify the WebEdit its not be able to identify the object.

![enter image description here][1]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is this snippet doing: `MsgBox Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebTable(webtableObj).WebEdit("class:=grid-dropdownbox", "index:=36").Exist(0)`?

Comment: What also got into mind: An `index` property is page-bound and not very usefull to identify objects in the a `WebTable`. If you want to use index as identifying property, add the `WebEdit` directly under the page object: `[...] Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebElement(webeditObj) [...]`

Comment: This is verifying if the object is available in the page.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I did what you have suggested. But no luck.

Comment: Yes, I know that is does that, that is why I am asking. And what does it do in you context? Does is return a `True` or a `False`?

Comment: OK, well, we have luck because that means that there is nothing wrong with you `webeditObject` function, but with the recognition of the objects. What happens if you do this: `MsgBox Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebEdit("class:=grid-dro‌​pdownbox", "index:=36").Exist(0)`?

Comment: Msgbox is showing False

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 37 `WebEdits` with class `grid-dropdownbox` on your page? Does getting the first WebEdit give you a positive result, like: `MsgBox Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebEdit("class:=grid-dro‌​pdownbox", "index:=0").Exist(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please change **Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebTable(webtableObj).WebElement(webeditObj).Set dict.Item("id")**

*into*
             **Browser(browserObj).Page(pageObj).WebTable(webtableObj).WebEdit(webeditObj).Set dict.Item("id")**

**Webelement().set "x"**  May work but not always.

"***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************"

It seems your **WebEdit** object is inside a **WebTable** So Please check whether it is dynamic(Some time property may change dynamically )

Instead of using **B().P().WebTable().WebEdit().set dict.Item("id")**

Try to use **Set oEdit  = B().P().Webtable().Childitem(row,column,"WebEdit",Index)**

**oEdit.Set dict.Item("id")**

Make sure the length of the textbox.

Don't forget to add **visible property**(Some times you may see only one text box in the page but there might be couple of textboxes hiding inside the page with same properties ...This might give problem when we try to set a value...Better  use Visible property )

Please let me know if the above mentioned  couldn't resolve the issue..

Comment: Thanks Arun for this answer its working now. The issue was accessing of the wrong properties.